# SQL server - Import of XML schema and data

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xsd

I am attempting to load a data feed from https://nvd.nist.gov/download.cfm. The site provides an XML schema and the data via XML files. I am new to SQL server, but I have done some research in attempt to import the database schema and data:

```
    CREATE XML SCHEMA COLLECTION NVE_XML_schema AS N'*<XML from link here>*';
```

Which results in an error:

```
    Msg 2308, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Reference to an undefined name 'vulnerabilityType' within namespace 'http://scap.nist.gov/schema/vulnerability/0.4'
```

Do I need to import this to the Schema collections to allow the database to read the data correctly?

Comment: The site you've linked to does not provide pure XML as far as I see... There are download links to zipped XML files... What are you really trying to load? What are you going to do with this? And no: AFAIK there's no easy-cheesy way to get an XML file via T-SQL out of the WWW. Have a llok at `sp_OACreate`, `sp_OAMethod` and `sp_OAGetProperty`...

Comment: @Shnugo There is a link for both the .XSD and the compressed XML's containing the data. I am attempting to build a vulnerability database to cross reference with a company's database containing hardware/firmware/software to create a notification when new vulnerabilities arise that could affect their infrastructure. To get the actual file, my plan is to use a python scrapper to check the meta file date to see if the db has been updated, then if it has been updated, I can download the 'modified' compressed file to add new vulnerabilities to the database. My issue is the importing of the XML data

Comment: Does this mean that you know how to check for modifiactions and how to load the file and how to un-zip it and your sole problem is how to import the XML?

Comment: @Shnugo Yes, they provide a meta file that changes each time they change the database (approx every 2 hours). I can use a python web scraper that uses regex to locate and download the needed files. I have just been trying to import the schema (a one-time operation), develop the tables (also one-time) that fit the schema, and import the modified xml data (each time there is a meta file mismatch).

Comment: XSD file: https://nvd.nist.gov/schema/nvd-cve-feed_2.0.xsd

Example meta file: https://static.nvd.nist.gov/feeds/xml/cve/2.0/nvdcve-2.0-Modified.meta 
Example XML data: http://static.nvd.nist.gov/feeds/xml/cve/nvdcve-2.0-Modified.xml.zip